# Excel 2007 Number with no decimals but not Auto-Rounded?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I seem to be having a fairly straightforward issue with Excel, although I cannot find a solution to it besides including a function.

Basically I would like to show a price in two fields, one for dollars and one for cents.

I have this working fine but the issue that I have is when I put say *"24990.55"* in the dollars field it will show *"24991"* in dollars and *"55"* in the cents field.

Is there any way I can force Excel to **NOT** Auto-Round?

Comment: as you said- you need to use function...

Comment: It's looking more and more like I do. Yay for needing to spend hours recoding my program due to something excel doesn't have the option to do

Comment: @adam2510 There is no way out without using functions!

Comment: @ColorlessPhoton I've attempted to use functions in it but it will still round up. I need it to stay at 24990.

Comment: @adam2510 Have you tried what teylyn has suggested below?

Comment: Yes I did... it showed "24990" as it should have but the cents wouldn't show at all... I think it would be best to hard code the split into my program rather than get excel to split it.

Comment: What do you mean with "The cents did not show at all?" I've added a screenshot to my post below.

Comment: This is still confusing, you say you have this working but just with rounding yet you are not using any functions?  A visual of what you have working would be helpful.

Comment: I've added a change event macro and another suggestion to my answer. Also, I feel it's high time that you came back and provided some clarification about your specs.

Comment: The reason why it isn't working is because I AM NOT getting the value from a third field, the total value is being passed to the dollars field and i need it to chop the cents of and put the cents in the cents field...

Comment: By passed I mean via my program... Only true solution I can see is to manually split the dollars and cents in my program.

Comment: What program are you using? VBA? Functions on the sheet?

Comment: INT(var) will cut off decimals, both as a spreadsheet function and in VBA as I show in my answer below. What is the problem?

Comment: Format your cell as text or general, dude.

Comment: Just post some kind of visual of what you want the end solution to look like.  Do you want the dollars to appear in one cell and the cents to appear in another like the solutions describe?  Please be more specific on what you want.  The solutions below work **perfect** as they are stated, but it seems that is not what you are looking for so update your question.

Comment: Is it wrong place to ask the question?

Comment: I think we could've used a little more context in the original question.  Like, why can't you use a formula?  Are you copy-pasting or importing a file?  Do you have lots of numbers or just one at a time?  I didn't ask these questions sooner because they just occurred to me :/  Anyway, learning experience for us all.

Answer (score 16):

If

`A1 = 24990.55`

then

- `=INT(A1)`  will return 24990
- `=MOD(A1,1)` will return 0.55

You need a function to cut off the decimals. `Int()` will do that. `Mod()` will show only the decimal points.

I don't know what behaviour you expect without using functions. Just formatting a number will **not** change its underlying value. This means that **there is no formatting** to show only the integer value and disregard the decimals without rounding. Excel does not work that way. Formatting to no decimal points will always include rounding. To work around that, you need a function to **cut off** the decimals.

If you want the cents to show as whole numbers, just multiply the `Mod()` result by 100.

[image]

Edit: You talk about functions above, but reading other responses, I think what you actually mean is [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) routine, a UDF or some other macro. You may want to get your terminology right when asking a question.

You really need to clarify what you want to achieve. It is not clear

- where you want the output, e.g. do you want the result in the same cell where the original number is entered? Where should the cents go, then?
- do you want the cents to be displayed as 0.55 or as 55?
- If you want the values (dollars and cents) to show in the same cell, what should that look like?
- if you want the values in two separate cells, please specify which cells for the dollars and which cells for the cents

Just putting a bounty on the question without clearly specifying your requirements does not help much.

Here is another approach, based on the following assumptions:

- the value with decimals is entered in column A
- the value should be changed in column A to show just the dollars (the integer)
- the value's decimals will be shown in column C
- the decimals will be shown as whole numbers in column B

This can be achieved by the following change event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Target - Int(Target)
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = (Target - Int(Target)) * 100
    Target = Int(Target)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Right-click the sheet tab, click "View Code" and paste the above code into the code window.

Of course, a much, much easier way to achieve exactly the same thing, without functions, without macros, without any VBA, can be done with exactly the same number of keystrokes as entering the number in a cell.

Compare these two sets of keystrokes

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

with

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

The second set of keystrokes will put the cents into their own cell, showing them as a whole number.

I'd really appreciate some feedback to the many suggestions that you have received in this thread.

Comment: @adam2510, if this does not solve your issue, can you please explain what you would like to see instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a second cell to calculate the value.
if your value is in cell A1, the formula would be

```
=A1-MOD(A1,1)
```

[image]

If it's an option, put your data entry on one worksheet (tab) and output the un-rounded output where you need the final answer..

Comment: Hi, @B-Rell.  Just curious why one would use this instead of `TRUNC`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this. However, if you want an *odd* solution:

- Assuming the value is in A1, enter the formulas in B1 and C1, see screenshot.
- Insert a **TextBox**. As you drag to create it over cell A1, hold the **Alt** key so that it will fit the cell perfectly.
- Click onto the edge of the TextBox and type `=C1` in the formula bar.
- Click the Align-Right button on Ribbon; you can right-click, Format Shape, for other options.
- Format the textbox to a white background, and no outline (border).
- You can hide column C.

[image]

You can copy and paste the shape into A2, it will change the formula to `=C2`. Use the Alt key again to resize the shape, if necessary, so that it fits the cell.

BTW: I am **not recommending this approach**, but it is an (unusual) answer to your question.

Comment: Why not just switch the formulas for B and C and then hide column A?  No need for text box then

Comment: I agree, but the OP specifically wants the value 24990 to show in the same cell that contains 24990.55, which is not possible.

Comment: The OP needs 3 cells, but thinks he needs only 2...that's the problem here

Answer (score 1):

Can you just format the cell as general or text? Those formats won't round.

Alternatively, you could `ROUNDDOWN` your dollars cell so it always displays the proper dollar figure.

You can also use a formula like

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)-1)
```

to separate the dollars and cents into separate cells. There are several ways to do this. It doesn't need to be complicated if you're willing to be a little creative.

Whatever route you take, you need to use 3 cells rather than 2. 1 cell for the full amount, 1 cell for dollars, and 1 cell for cents. You must have an input cell and 2 cells with formulas if you're not going to use code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for giggles, here's another solution.

Assuming you have existing data in columns, and you want to split the dollars and cents into two separate columns,  you can use the **Text to Columns** feature.

In Excel 2007:

[image: On the Data tab, select Text to Columns]

Note that we're on the Data tab.  With your column highlighted, select **Text to Columns** and you'll get the below dialog. Selected **Delimited** and hit next.

[image: Excel 2007 text-to-columns wizard, step 1 of 3]

On this screen, select **Other** and put a period into the field, like so:

[image: Excel 2007 text-to-columns wizard, step 2 of 3]

At this point, you can hit Finish and it will split them into two columns!  Woohoo!

If you want to choose the destination and formatting for the fields, hit Next.

[image: eExcel 2007 text-to-columns wizard, step 2 of 3]

Fancy!

Oh and here's the results:

[image: Dollars and cents!]

Hurray, Excel!

Answer (score 0):

The number of decimals to be displayed can be set on the Tools menu under options.Select the number of decimals under Fixed decimal options.
Alternately you can use the INT function to extract only the integer portion of the value having decimals.

Comment: Both of these still round the number which is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't see how this is possible without functions.

The function you want is `TRUNC`.  This will simply drop the decimal portion of your number.

Comment: And for cents I would just use `RIGHT(<cell ref>, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you need to display something like this...
[image]

And for achieving that you need to format that cell and in format you need to do this.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

TRUNC function does not round numbers. ... The TRUNC function, short for truncate function is used to remove the decimal part of a number to a set

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - sounds to me like the `TRUNC` function is exactly what is needed here.

Comment: I'm not questioning that. I'm questioning that chetan comments answer by Charles instead of answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

really you just need to use the left and find then add the number of decimals you want after the find.  E.g., `=LEFT(H4,FIND(".",H4)+2)`

Answer (score 0):

This is DEFINITELY possible!  There is a clever workaround to show decimals as whole cents using a number format, and WITHOUT changing the actual value in the cell.  Right click the cell and select Format Cells.  On the Number tab, go to Custom.

In the custom number format "Type" field copy/paste the following:

```
# ¢
```

Then type this keyboard combination:

```
CTRL + J
```

And finally:

```
%
```

Click OK to save the custom number format.  Then set the cell format to "Wrap Text".

The % symbol multiplies the number by 100 so your 0.37 shows as 37.  It also adds a percent symbol to the format which you don't want.

CTRL + J hides the percent symbol by inserting a CHR(10) line break that moves the percent symbol to a second line in the cell.  Excel won't auto-increase the row height for this cell so it stays hidden.

The end result is that a cell value of 0.37 displays as 37 ¢.  For me this is much better than changing the cell value with a formula.